# FireStore Swift 4 : How to get total count of all the documents inside a collection, and get details of each document?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Console Image]

I need to get all the users count from superuser and list those in a table view with there details.
Is there a code to directly get the count of documents inside a collection, other than using functions inside firebase console.
Or a Simple Query to traverse through the documents!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this will collect all the document for a collection and print them

```
db.collection("superUsers").getDocuments() 
{ 
    (querySnapshot, err) in

    if let err = err 
    {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
    } 
    else 
    {
        var count = 0
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            count += 1
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
        }

        print("Count = \(count)");
    }
}
```

Comment: (I know this is an old post, but...) is this not potentially really slow?... what if the user count was Facebook-level numbers?

You would be downloading the user documents of EVERY user, no?.... Eventually that has to impact on performance

Comment: @Andy I think the time I wrote this answer, there was no way to get the count directly, but as you can see some changes are done and now you can get the count directly  `snapshot.count`

Comment: yeh, but is it not still potentially an issue with where you have to download several million documents from Firestore?... even if you only run snapshot.count?

Or am I missing some vital understanding of the way Firestore works? lol

Answer (score 9):

You can count the documents in a snapshot:

```
snapshot.count
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
querySnapshot.documents.count
```

When you receive a SnapShot, it includes documents as you see in your FireStore Web Page. then you must get `documents.count` to get number of documents in that particular hierarchy you requested for.

Comment: Please do not post only code as answer. Please explain your answer/implementation.