# FireStore Swift: Accessing counts and document details for use in a table

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The code from [FireStore Swift 4 : How to get total count of all the documents inside a collection, and get details of each document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516763/firestore-swift-4-how-to-get-total-count-of-all-the-documents-inside-a-collect) is correctly printing to the console when called in the viewDidLoad part of my TableViewController. However, I am trying to use "count" for the number of rows, and pick out some of the document details to display in the table.

The problem I am having now is that these details seem locked in this QuerySnapshot call, and I can't access them in numberOfRowsInSection and CellForRowAt. I'm using version 10 of xcode. Sorry if this is a noob question, but I've been stumped for a while.

```
var count = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let reviewTopic = Firestore.firestore().collection("usersIds").document(userEmail!).collection("reviews")
    reviewTopic.getDocuments() {
        (QuerySnapshot,err) in

        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        } else {
            for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                self.count += 1
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
            }
            print("Count = \(self.count)"); 
        }
        print("Count from viewDidLoad: ", self.count) // prints 2
    }
}
```

Again, the above returns the correct counts (2) and document details, but I am trying to use the value in numberOfRowsInSection, which runs before viewDidLoad and returns 0.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Count from numrows: ", self.count)
    return self.count //returns value of 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to reload your `UITableView` once you got the data from the server so you need to reload your `UITableView` with:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

After the `for` loop. Because it's an asynchronous call where you need to wait until you got the data from the server.

And your code will look like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let reviewTopic = Firestore.firestore().collection("usersIds").document(userEmail!).collection("reviews")
    reviewTopic.getDocuments() {
        (QuerySnapshot,err) in

        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        } else {
            for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                self.count += 1
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
            }
            print("Count = \(self.count)"); 
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        print("Count from viewDidLoad: ", self.count) // prints 2
    }
}
```

One more thing you should create a class object and store all the data into a class object and then access that data into your `cellforrow` and `numberofrows` method. Or you can use `Codable` protocol to parse your `JSON` from server and store the server data.

And with that you can easily manage your `UITableView` datasource and you can also find out which cell is pressed easily.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)